# Python Permissions 2.7 and upgrade to 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been fighting something for almost 3 days now.  I have a simple Python program first with XLSXwriter and now OpenpyXLS so I don't think it is related to the package as they behave the same.

It runs fine on 2.7 but if I switch to 3.7 it fails with a permissions error.  If I type it in the 3.7 interpreter it runs fine.  Been using Python 2.7 installed right at C:\Python27.  Decided I should move to 3 so I used the Python3 installer to install at C:\Python37.  I set it up so python2 at a cmd prompt starts 2.7 and python starts 3.7.  When I try to run this in 2.7 it is fine and 3.7 fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import openpyxl
import os


print(os.getcwd())

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

for module in range(1,20):
    ws = wb.create_sheet("M" + str(module))
    ws.cell(row=1, column=1, value='Current')
    for y in range(1,21):
        ws.cell(row=1, column=y+1, value='M'+ str(module) +'_CV'+ str(y))

wb.save('testfile.xlsx')
```

The error is:

```
C:\Users\PF Flyers\Python\CAN>python2 work_dummy.py
C:\Users\PF Flyers\Python\CAN

C:\Users\PF Flyers\Python\CAN>python work_dummy.py
C:\Users\PF Flyers\Python\CAN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work_dummy.py", line 17, in <module>
    wb.save('testfile.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 391, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 282, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testfile.xlsx'
```

I have checked permissions on both python directories they seem to be the same. Permission on the working directory are fine.  I have used absolute file paths, osjoin etc.  I have ran the cmd prompt with admin right etc.  I just can't get it to work under 3.7 and I am stumped.

EDIT:

Still working on this and I am down to basics.  I have this simple bit of code.

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.Workbook('New.xlsx')
>>> wb.save('Test.xlsx')
>>>
```

It works fine.  When I run it from the command line with a file open and it fails on the permissions when it saves the Test.xlsx file with Permissions error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import openpyxl

file = open('New.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())

wb = openpyxl.Workbook('New.xlsx')
wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

The open statement works and prints the contents of the .txt but if I change the open statement to New.xlsx I then get the failure on that.  For some reason it seems related to xlsx files but I have no idea why and why it would work fine in the interpreter.

Comment: the excel file is not open in Excel by accident? Excel locks this file for writing then.

Comment: Not that I know of.  I even even looked at Task manager and I didn't see anything.